# How to add more result matrix in our summary report

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, surefire

As part of the continuous integration task I'm owning, I have been able to add lots of selenium WebDriver scripts in Java and Eclipse.  Basically, using a maven project, I have written various java scripts using Selenium and am now able to run the automated tests using Jenkins after the nightly build is deployed.  In addition, I am able to successfully create a surefire-report.html.  Howoever, this report only contains the following matrix:

```
Tests   Errors  Failures    Skipped Success Rate    Time
38      4       2           18      36.842%         746.477
```

The development manager has requested to see the following matrix as well:

```
TRR = (Number of tests run) / (Total number of tests available)
TPR = (Number of test passed) / (number of tests run)
```

Is there any way I can modify the surefire report in order to add the above matrix results as well?

Comment: Not sure if it is possible using surefire, but definitely available with other reporting plugins.

Comment: @Waman:  Thanks. Can you please suggest other plugins that have this feature?  What plugin should I use?  What should be included in my pom file? How can I create different test matix results other than the default ones?

Answer (score 0):

Look for PerfPublisher plugin in Jenkins.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PerfPublisher+Plugin

This will by default give you the following things:
1. Number of tests run
2. Number of total tests.
3. Number of tests passed and failed.

So you have all required values there :)
The only change you would need to do is to create an XML file of particular format:

```
<report name="{REPORT_NAME}" categ="{CATEGORY_NAME}">
<test name="{TEST_NAME1}" executed="{EXECUTED_STATUS}">
 <result>
 <success passed="{RESULT_STATUS}" state="{RESULT_STATE}"/>
 </result>
</test>
 <test name="{TEST_NAME2}" executed="{EXECUTED_STATUS}">
 <result>
 <success passed="{RESULT_STATUS}" state="{RESULT_STATE}"/>
 </result>
</test>
</report>
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Where should I create this XML file?  What should I name it (does it matter?)  How can I provide equations to calculate TRR and TPR matrix results?

Comment: Create the XML file in your job's work space, Node doesn't matter only you need it to identity report file incase there are multiple files parsed during single run of reporting. Incase you would like calculate TRR & TPR, you can have separate job for reporting and then parsing its console output file you could get the required values to calculate TRR and TPR.